# Auto clicker that lets me select region and continue using the mouse elsewhere

Tags: scripts, mouse, software-recommendation

All the other auto clicker apps/scripts I found, like `xautoclick` and `xdotool`, need me to leave my mouse in the position and then the auto click is done. But I'm looking for something like NIAutoclicker, but for Ubuntu. I'll select the region on the webpage, leave it in the background, and continue using the mouse as I see fit.